# Unit test typescript types

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, typescript-typings

I have the following export in one of my modules:

```
export class Action1 implements Action {}

export class Action2 implements Action {}

export type ActionsUnion =
  | Action1
  | Action2;
```

I am trying to work out the best way to test `ActionsUnion` to make sure it is of the types I have defined. For example:

```
it('should have the correct types', () => {
  expect(typeof Action1).toEqual(ActionsUnion);
  expect(typeof Action2).toEqual(ActionsUnion);
});
```

Of course the above doesn't work as I am using `ActionsUnion` as a variable. Any ideas on how to achieve the above?

For context, I am using angular, ngrx and jasmine.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is there any check that's not performed by compiler?

Comment: We use `dtslint` to test RxJS's type declarations: https://github.com/Microsoft/dtslint You could also look at [`ts-snippet`](https://github.com/cartant/ts-snippet) - I'd initially planned on using that to test RxJS's types, but `dtslint` is much better suited to writing a large number of expectations.

Comment: @Cerberus I want to have a test that ensures `ActionsUnion` type contains all the corresponding class types.

@cartant - thanks for the suggestions, I will take a look

Comment: Related: [2ality Blog Dr. Axel Rauschmayer: "Testing static types in TypeScript"](https://2ality.com/2019/07/testing-static-types.html) (incl. discussion)

Answer (score 1):

[tsafe](https://github.com/garronej/tsafe) enables to unit test types, example:

```js
// This test file is not meant to be executed, if there is not TS errors, it passes.


import { assert, Equals } from "tsafe";

declare function myFunction<T extends string>(arr: T[]): T;

{

  const got = myFunction([ "a", "b", "c" ]);

  type Got = typeof got;

  type Expect = "a" | "b";

  // Here we have a TS error, as we should, because:
  // Got is        "a" | "b" | "c"
  // and Expect is "a" | "b"
  assert<Equals<Got, Expect>>();

}

{

  const got = myFunction([ "a", "b", "c" ]);

  type Got = typeof got;

  type Expect = "a" | "b" | "c";

  // ✅ Got and Expect are the same type
  assert<Equals<Got, Expect>>();

}

{

  //@ts-expect-error: We shouldn't be allowed to pass numbers
  myFunction([ "a", 42, "c" ]);

}

{

    // Here we got some red because we say we expect an 
    // error but the expression is valid
    //@ts-expect-error
    myFunction([ "a", "b", "c" ]);

}

{

  const got = myFunction([ "a", "b", "c" ]);

  type Got = typeof got;


  // We can also validate that 
  assert<Got extends string ? true : false>();


}

{

  type T = "a" | "b";
  type U = string;

  // We expect that T extends U
  assert<T extends U ? true : false>();

}
```

In the example of the question:

```js
import { assert } from "tsafe/assert";
import type { Extends } from "tsafe";

type Action= { _signature: undefined; }

 class Action1 implements Action {
   _signature: undefined;
 }

 class Action2 implements Action {
  _signature: undefined;
 }

export type ActionsUnion =
  | Action1
  | Action2;

assert<Extends<Action1, ActionsUnion>>();
```

Disclosure: I am the author.

Answer (score -3):

I have not tried it with a union, but you may want to try jasmine.any(Type).  In this case your code above would be:

```
it('should have the correct types', () => {
  expect(Action1).toEqual(jasmine.any(ActionsUnion));
  expect(Action2).toEqual(jasmine.any(ActionsUnion));
});
```

Details here: 
https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Matching_Anything_with_%3Ccode%3Ejasmine.any%3C/code%3E

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I get a TS Lint error, `error TS2693: 'ActionsUnion' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` And then on execution, `ReferenceError: ActionsUnion is not defined`

Comment: This is totally wrong. You messed type and value up.